# Identification of quotient involving the Hilbert Modular Group

Tags: number-theory, quotient-spaces, modular-forms, modular-group

$K$ is a real quadratic number field with ring of integers $\mathcal O_K$.

In Zagiers *Modular Forms Associated to Real Quadratic Fields* from 1975 at page 6 he introduces a surjective map
$$m : S\to T$$
where $T$ is given by
$$T=\{ (\mu,\nu)\in (\mathfrak a \times \mathfrak a \setminus \{(0,0)\})/\mathcal{O}_K^\times : \delta(\mu,\nu)=\mathfrak a \}$$
where $\mathfrak a$ is a fraktional ideal representing its ideal class. For $\mathfrak a=\mathcal O_K$ it is possible to regard $T$ as the quotient
$$\Gamma_\infty \backslash \Gamma_K$$
$\Gamma_K$ being $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathcal O_K)$ and $\Gamma_\infty$ the subgroup stabilizing the cusp $\infty$. The identification maps an element of $\Gamma_\infty \backslash \Gamma_K$ to its lower row.

I was wondering if there is such an identification for other fraktional ideals as well. Is there some subgroup $\Gamma \subset \operatorname{SL}_2(K)$ such that you can identify $T$ with $\Gamma_\infty \backslash \Gamma$?

Comment: @reuns Do you mean $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathfrak a \oplus \mathfrak a)$? That might be a good idea. So far I only know the definition of $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathcal O_K \oplus \mathfrak a)$. That doesn't seem to work. But I'd like to learn the definition of $\operatorname{SL}_2( \mathfrak a \oplus \mathfrak b)$. Can you state it?

Comment: With $SL(\mathfrak{a}\times \mathfrak{a})$ I meant the subgroup of $SL_2(K)$ sending $\mathfrak{a}\times \mathfrak{a}$ to itself?

Comment: @reuns Is that group maybe $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathcal O_K)$? At least $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathcal O_K)$ should be contained in that group since it sends $\mathfrak a \times \mathfrak a$ to itself.